# What is an alternative way to convert from a tuple array type to a named tuple array type?

Tags: arrays, swift, type-conversion, tuples

In Swift, `[(String, Double)]` and `[(name: String, result: Double)]` are not compatible! To convert between these to types, I can only change the type name, which is so *brute force*.

I mean, these two types are *logically* compatible, right? Just throw away the name and you get `[(String, Double)]`. Add the names and you get `[(name: String. result: Double)]`.

For now, I can only loop through the array and add each item to the variable of the other type. Which is so many lines of code just to do this!

What is a more elegant way to convert between these two types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map:

```
let tupleArray: [(String, Double)] = [("element A", 2.5),("element B", 5.0)]
let tuppleNamedArray: [(name: String, result: Double)] = tupleArray.map{($0,$1)}
tuppleNamedArray.first?.result   // 2.5
```

or also as suggested by vacawama:

```
let tuppleNamedArray = tupleArray.map{(name: $0, result: $1)}
```

Comment: Or more succinctly: `let tuppleNamedArray = tupleArray.map{(name: $0, result: $1)}`